# How do I create this query using rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In rails, how can I create the following query in rails? I know how to write it in SQL. I would know if it's possible using rails.

The following code:

```
one_day_ago = 1.days.ago.at_beginning_of_day;
Client.joins(:user => {:cart => [:cart_items, :saved_items]}).where('cart_items.created_at > ?', one_day_ago).group('clients.user_id')
```

The code above creates the following query:

```
SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `clients`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `carts` ON `carts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `cart_items` ON `cart_items`.`cart_id` = `carts`.`id` 
AND `cart_items`.`type` IN ('CartItem') 
INNER JOIN `cart_items` `saved_items_carts` ON `saved_items_carts`.`cart_id` = `carts`.`id` 
AND `saved_items_carts`.`type` IN ('SavedItem')
WHERE (cart_items.created_at > '2019-03-31 04:00:00.000000') GROUP BY clients.user_id
```

How can I get rails to create a query like this:

SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `clients`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `carts` ON `carts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `cart_items` ON `cart_items`.`cart_id` = `carts`.`id` 
WHERE (cart_items.created_at > '2019-03-31 04:00:00.000000' 
AND cart_items.type IN ('SavedItem','CartItem')) GROUP BY clients.user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you'd want the second part to have an OR, but you can write the join query however you want:

```
Client.joins(user: { cart: [:cart_items] }).joins("INNER JOIN cart_items saved_cart_items ON saved_cart_items.cart_id = carts.id OR saved_cart_items.type IN ('SavedItem')").where('cart_items.created_at > ?', one_day_ago).group('clients.user_id')
```

See if this updated query gives you the desired output:

```
Client
.joins(:user, :cart)
.joins('INNER JOIN cart_items ON cart_items.id = carts.id')
.where('cart_items.created_at > ?', one_day_ago)
.where(cart_items: { type: ['SavedItem', 'CartItem'] })
.group('clients.user_id')
```

Comment: sorry about that, I updated the code to the query I'm trying to achieve.